# specify CFA with turbulances being the sum of exogenous correlations

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I am trying to specify a curious model in lavaan in R language.
The model looks like this:
[image]

My specification attempt is shown bellow. What I find difficult to achieve is to fix the unique error of the observed variables to be the sum of two correlations of unique items.

for instance item y*1,2 covaries with y*1,3 and y*2,3 and its error is supposed to be cov y*1,3 + cov y*1,3.

How can I explicitly fix the item error to equal the sum of these covariances in the lavaan syntax bellow?

```
cfa_model_spesification<-'
                          C=~   #C4_12*i10i11+C4_13*i10i12+
                                #C5_12*i13i14+C5_13*i13i15+
                                #C6_12*i17i18+C6_13*i17i19+
                                C1_12*i1i2+C1_13*i1i3+
                                C2_12*i4i5+C2_13*i4i6+
                                C3_12*i7i8+C3_13*i7i9

                          R=~   #R4_23*i10i11+R4_12*i11i12+
                                #R5_23*i13i14+R5_12*i14i16+
                                #R6_23*i17i18+R6_12*i18i19+
                                R1_12*i1i2+R1_23*i2i3+
                                R2_12*i4i5+R2_23*i5i6+
                                R3_12*i7i8+R3_23*i8i9

                          O=~   #O4_13*i10i12+O4_23*i11i12+
                                #O5_13*i13i15+O5_23*i14i16+
                                #O6_13*i17i19+O6_23*i18i19+
                                O1_13*i1i3+O1_23*i2i3+
                                O2_13*i4i6+O2_23*i5i6+
                                O3_13*i7i9+O3_23*i8i9

                          O~~1*O
                          C~~1*C
                          R~~1*R

                          O~~C+R
                          R~~C

                          R1_23==-R1_12
                          R2_23==-R2_12
                          R3_23==-R3_12

                          R1_23>0
                          R2_23>0
                          R3_23>0
                          # R1_12<0
                          # R2_12<0
                          # R3_12<0

                          O1_13<0
                          O1_23<0
                          O2_13<0
                          O2_23<0
                          O3_13<0
                          O3_23<0

                          i1i2~~i1i3
                          i1i2~~i2i3
                          i1i3~~i2i3

                          i4i5~~i4i6
                          i4i5~~i5i6
                          i4i6~~i5i6

                          i7i8~~i7i9
                          i7i8~~i8i9
                          i7i9~~i8i9

                          i1i2~~1*i1i2
                          i4i5~~1*i4i5
                          i7i8~~1*i7i8

                          # i1i3~~equal("i1i3~~i1i2+i1i3~~i2i3")*i1i3
                          # i2i3~~equal("i2i3~~i1i2+i2i3~~i1i3")*i2i3
                          # i4i6~~equal("i4i6~~i4i5+i4i6~~i5i6")*i4i6
                          # i5i6~~equal("i5i6~~i4i5+i5i6~~i4i6")*i5i6
                          # i7i9~~equal("i7i9~~i7i8+i7i9~~i8i9")*i7i9
                          # i8i9~~equal("i8i9~~i7i8+i8i9~~i7i9")*i8i9
'
```

The syntax for this in mplus looks like this

```
TITLE:
Example
DATA:
FILE IS triplets.dat;

VARIABLE: 
NAMES=i1i2 i1i3 i2i3 i4i5 i4i6 i5i6 i7i8 i7i9 i8i9 i10i11 i10i12 i11i12;
CATEGORICAL=i1i2-i11i12;
ANALYSIS: 
ESTIMATOR=ulsmv; 
PARAMETERIZATION=THETA;
MODEL: 
Trait1 BY
i1i2*1 i1i3*1 (L1)
i4i5*-1 i4i6*-1 (L4)
i7i8*1 i7i9*1 (L7)
i10i11*1 i10i12*1 (L10);
Trait2 BY
i1i2*-1 (L2_n)
i2i3*1 (L2)
i4i5*-1 (L5_n)
i5i6*1 (L5)
i7i8*-1 (L8_n)
i8i9*1 (L8)
i10i11*1 (L11_n)
i11i12*-1 (L11);
Trait3 BY 
i1i3*-1 i2i3*-1 (L3_n)
i4i6*-1 i5i6*-1 (L6_n)
i7i9*1 i8i9*1 (L9_n)
i10i12*-1 i11i12*-1 (L12_n);

Trait1-Trait3@1
Trait1 WITH Trait2*-0.4 Trait3*0;
Trait2 WITH Trait3*0.3;

i1i2*2 (e1e2);
i1i3*2 (e1e3);
i2i3*2 (e2e3);
i4i5*2 (e4e5);
i4i6*2 (e4e6);
i5i6*2 (e5e6);
i7i8*2 (e7e8);
i7i9*2 (e7e9);
i8i9*2 (e8e9);
i10i11*2 (e10e11);
i10i12*2 (e10e12);
i11i12*2 (e11e12);

i1i2 WITH i1i3*1 (e1);
i1i2 WITH i2i3*-1 (e2_n);
i1i3 WITH i2i3*1 (e3);
i4i5 WITH i4i6*1 (e4);
i4i5 WITH i5i6*-1 (e5_n);
i4i6 WITH i5i6*1 (e6);
i7i8 WITH i7i9*1 (e7);
i7i8 WITH i8i9*-1 (e8_n);
i7i9 WITH i8i9*1 (e9);
i10i11 WITH i10i12*1 (e10);
i10i11 WITH i11i12*-1 (e11_n);
i10i12 WITH i11i12*1 (e12);

MODEL CONSTRAINT:
L2_n=-L2;
L5_n=-L5;
L8_n=-L8;
L11_n=-L11;

e1e2=e1-e2_n;
e1e3=e1+e3;
e2e3=-e2_n+e3;
e4e5=e4-e5_n;
e4e6=e4+e6;
e5e6=-e5_n+e6;
e7e8=e7-e8_n;
e7e9=e7+e9;
e8e9=-e8_n+e9;
e10e11=e10-e11_n;
e10e12=e10+e12;
e11e12=-e11_n+e12;

e1=1;
e4=1;
e7=1;
e10=1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the model spesification with lavaan I came up with for a tirt model

```
lavaan_6_model_spesification<-'# factor loadings (lambda)
trait1=~start(1)*L1*i1i2+start(1)*L1*i1i3+start(1)*L4*i4i5+start(1)*L4*i4i6+start(1)*L7*i7i8+start(1)*L7*i7i9+start(1)*L10*i10i11+start(1)*L10*i10i12+start(1)*L13*i13i14+start(1)*L13*i13i15+start(1)*L16*i16i17+start(1)*L16*i16i18
trait2=~start(-1)*L2n*i1i2+start(1)*L2*i2i3+start(-1)*L5n*i4i5+start(1)*L5*i5i6+start(-1)*L8n*i7i8+start(1)*L8*i8i9+start(-1)*L11n*i10i11+start(1)*L11*i11i12+start(-1)*L14n*i13i14+start(1)*L14*i14i15+start(-1)*L17n*i16i17+start(1)*L17*i17i18
trait3=~start(-1)*L3n*i1i3+start(-1)*L3n*i2i3+start(-1)*L6n*i4i6+start(-1)*L6n*i5i6+start(-1)*L9n*i7i9+start(-1)*L9n*i8i9+start(-1)*L12n*i10i12+start(-1)*L12n*i11i12+start(-1)*L15n*i13i15+start(-1)*L15n*i14i15+start(-1)*L18n*i16i18+start(-1)*L18n*i17i18

# fix factor variances to 1
trait1~~1*trait1
trait2~~1*trait2
trait3~~1*trait3

# factor correlations
trait1~~trait2+trait3
trait2~~trait3

# fix factor loadings of the same item to the same value
L2==-L2n
L5==-L5n
L8==-L8n
L11==-L11n
L14==-L14n
L17==-L17n

# declare uniquenesses (psi)
i1i2~~P1P2*i1i2
i1i3~~P1P3*i1i3
i2i3~~P2P3*i2i3
i4i5~~P4P5*i4i5
i4i6~~P4P6*i4i6
i5i6~~P5P6*i5i6
i7i8~~P7P8*i7i8
i7i9~~P7P9*i7i9
i8i9~~P8P9*i8i9
i10i11~~P10P11*i10i11
i10i12~~P10P12*i10i12
i11i12~~P11P12*i11i12
i13i14~~P13P14*i13i14
i13i15~~P13P15*i13i15
i14i15~~P14P15*i14i15
i16i17~~P16P17*i16i17
i16i18~~P16P18*i16i18
i17i18~~P17P18*i17i18

# correlated uniqunesses
i1i2~~start(1)*P1*i1i3
i1i2~~start(-1)*P2n*i2i3
i1i3~~start(1)*P3*i2i3
i4i5~~start(1)*P4*i4i6
i4i5~~start(-1)*P5n*i5i6
i4i6~~start(1)*P6*i5i6
i7i8~~start(1)*P7*i7i9
i7i8~~start(-1)*P8n*i8i9
i7i9~~start(1)*P9*i8i9
i10i11~~start(1)*P10*i10i12
i10i11~~start(-1)*P11n*i11i12
i10i12~~start(1)*P12*i11i12
i13i14~~start(1)*P13*i13i15
i13i14~~start(-1)*P14n*i14i15
i13i15~~start(1)*P15*i14i15
i16i17~~start(1)*P16*i16i18
i16i17~~start(-1)*P17n*i17i18
i16i18~~start(1)*P18*i17i18

# pairs uniqueness is equal to sum of 2 utility uniqunesses
P1P2==P1-P2n
P1P3==P1+P3
P2P3==-P2n+P3
P4P5==P4-P5n
P4P6==P4+P6
P5P6==-P5n+P6
P7P8==P7-P8n
P7P9==P7+P9
P8P9==-P8n+P9
P10P11==P10-P11n
P10P12==P10+P12
P11P12==-P11n+P12
P13P14==P13-P14n
P13P15==P13+P15
P14P15==-P14n+P15
P16P17==P16-P17n
P16P18==P16+P18
P17P18==-P17n+P18

# fix one uniqueness per block for identification
P1==1
P4==1
P7==1
P10==1
P13==1
P16==1
# force item parameters of the same item to be equal
'
```